# How to make readonly input behave like div with css?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a readonly input just appear more or less like a block level element. However, I don't want to just set the width to 100%, I need it to behave as if the content adjusts the width automatically like it normally would.

CSS:

```
input:read-only, textarea:read-only {
    border: 0;
    outline:0;
    height: auto;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    font-weight: 300;
    display:block;
}
```

To make this clear, I'm trying to make an input behave like the following would:

```
<div>
    someone@somelongdomainbecausewhynot.com
</div>
```

It's close, although the initial default browser 'width' of the input field restricts or appears as if the input has an overflow set. I've tried setting the overflow too but this also didn't work.

I would like to keep this limited to CSS only, I don't want to have to use javascript here.

UPDATED DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hhz17uww/6/

Comment: I may have misinterpreted what you're after, but If you use width: 100% it will only scale the input field to the size of its inner content, it wont display as a full span block element?

Comment: Yes of course, I need the input to behave like a block element itself, so width 100% will not work

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a div with `class="readonly"` and the use some styles on that class?

Comment: Same question. In fact I wonder if it's even possible without javascript. You can use something like <span contenteditable="true">dummy text</span>, but it also beats the purpose of "read only".

Comment: Yes it would be easier, but I don't have that luxury hence why I asked this question. @JoaquínO

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want the `input` to fill the width of the container, but using `width: 100%` isn't ideal as the parent may have margin or padding.  If this is the case use:

```
input:read-only {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now the input element will take up all available space and take into account the parents margin and padding.

For more info on `box-sizing` read Paul Irish's post [box-sizing border-box ftw](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Answer (score 0):

Here You can follow this rule to achieve your assignment.

> The **inherit** CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to
>   take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It is
>   allowed on every CSS property. For inherited properties, this
>   reinforces the default behavior, and is only needed to **override**
>   another rule.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="email" name="email" class="emailField"  readonly="readonly" value="someone@somelongdomainbecausewhynot.com" />
</div>
<p>someone@somelongdomainbecausewhynot.com</p>


input:read-only {
    border: 0;
    width: inherit;
    display:block;
    margin: 1.12em 0 ;
  font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
```

This will inherit Parent element`<div>` width, Any How we need to customize width of Parent.

[**Working Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/su6pqk5e/1/)

Comment: This uses width 100% which I specifically said I didn't want to use because I wanted the input to naturally adapt it's width

Comment: If Your Assumption is to adopt Width ,then we need to customize atleast parent element width ,check out revised solution and demo link for details @ShannonHochkins

Comment: This still doesn't help as it still requires a fixed width

Answer (score -1):

Your styles are not being applied because you are using a pseudo selector that doesn't exist: `:read-only`. You can use the classname or another selector. Here's an updated fiddle using `.emailField`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hhz17uww/4/

Comment: You've obviously completely misunderstood my question, and the pseudo selector :read-only does exist.... It's clearly styling my input

Comment: I did read your question and did my best to answer it. The fiddle I made shows the styles showing up. 'readonly' was definitely not applying styles in my browser.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Mozilla or IE then?

Comment: If it doesn't work in Mozilla or je then why would you want a non cross platform solution?

Comment: @Alex who said this was for public use? It's an internal project, browser doesn't matter however Id on't have control of this view.

Comment: Hey, you didn't mention that in your question, I'm just stating the obvious. In general it's still bad practice